# How can i make the List size not remaining always zero

Tags: java

I have a list in lotto and I am inserting object lottoTicket in it. like shown below

```
if(choice.equals("P"))
{
   int i = 1;

   System.out.println("Choose a number between 1 and 90:");
   List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
   list.add(s.nextInt());


   LottoTicket lt = new LottoTicket("Prima",money * 60,list, i++);
   Lotto l = new Lotto();
   l.li.add(lt);     

}
```

The problem I have is that in the lotto i have li.size() which is always printing 0 (thus always returning 0 ) even if i have created 3 objects and assigned them to the list already. The below code is in the Lotto Class.

```
List<LottoTicket> li = new ArrayList();

@Override
public void draw(){

    Random rand = new Random();     

    int[] array = new int[6];


    for (int i = 1; i < array.length ; i++) {  
        array[i] = rand.nextInt(91) + 1;
        System.out.println("Tickets sold: " + li.size());
        System.out.print(""+ array[i] + ",");
    }


}
```

Comment: You may want to post your entire method definitions.  It looks like you might be creating a new Lotto object for each ticket and not storing it anywhere, but I can't be sure.

Comment: maybe the problem is that than that i am insertin anything in the list could  you please tell me what i need to do because the above code is all i have related to this problem

Comment: LottoTicket lt = new LottoTicket("Prima",money * 60,list, i++) is what i want to assign to the li list

Answer (score 0):

From the code snippet above it is not apparent to me where you are adding the contents of the array `array` to `li`. The for loop in the draw function merely assigns a value to `array` but never adds anything to list. It is also worth noting that since you initialize `i = 1` to one you are only generating 5 random numbers stored in `array` locations 1 through 5 and `array` location 0 is never accessed

Comment: i am adding it using l.li.add(lt); li is the array list i have in the Lotto Class

Comment: no what i want to assign is  LottoTicket lt = new LottoTicket("Prima",money * 60,list, i++) not the array

Answer (score 0):

Without more code it's pretty much impossible to 'guess' what your problem may be, but as a stab in the dark, I'm going to assume that your `Lotto` object isn't global.

```
LottoTicket lt = new LottoTicket("Prima",money * 60,list, i++);
Lotto l = new Lotto();
l.li.add(lt);
```

This part here, seems to me like you're creating a new `Lotto` object every time. Instead, why not define it as class global, so that you can gaurauntee that you only have one object. Like so:

```
// Top of the class(global scope)
private Lotto mLotto = new Lotto();
```

Then you can access it anywhere within that class and know that you're only accessing the 1 object.

As an aside, it's terribly poor coding to expose members to external classes, unless you have no choice (but there usually is always a choice!), in this instance I'd use something like the following:

```
class Lotto {
    // define as private to avoid possible errors later on
    private List<LottoTicket> mTickets = new ArrayList<LottoTicket>();

    // define getter to return the list as a whole
    public List<LottoTicket> getTickets() { return mTickets; }

    // define an add Ticket method to add the data to the object, rather than 
    // access Lotto.li.add etc...
    public void addTicketToList(LottoTicket thisTicket){
        mTickets.add(thisTicket);
    }
}
```

So in the scenario of your code above you'd use something like:

```
LottoTicket lt = new LottoTicket("Prima",money * 60,list, i++);

// Replace all this
// Lotto l = new Lotto();
// l.li.add(lt);   

// with
myGlobalLottoObject.addTicketToList(lt);

// And then loop through the collected tickets with something like:
foreach(LottoTicket lt : myGlobalLottoObject.getTickets())
{
    // Do something here with each "lt" object that is returned
}
```

You're on the right track, but you're missing some fundamental understanding of classes and code structure. Hopefully this will help you get to the bottom of your issue.

Obviously if this doesn't help you, then you'll have to post more relevant code, in order for us to be able to see exactly where you're going wrong.